# If 0 items in DB table, return error

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to display an error message if there is nothing listed in the table.

I have a photos table.

If this tables is empty, id like to echo something.

else, show the pictures.

inside of that table I have

```
id, name, url
id = id
name = name of image
url = url of image.
```

If there are no rows, we have an error.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos;");
mysql_fetch_array($query1);
if(empty($query1)) {
echo "nothing";
} else {
echo "good";
}
```

Comment: thanks, good question. i started a query SELECT COUNT (*) FROM photos. if(query1 = 0) show error

Comment: Use `if()`, `empty()` on your query result

Comment: Can you add the code with question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like...

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS amountPhotos FROM photos";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row["amountPhotos"] == 0) {
  echo "There are no photos in the photo table.";
}
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo "There are no photos in the photo table.";
}
```

Comment: I picked this one because it was the most simplictic. The others worked well, but this was easier. Thanks @tobse

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$length= mysql_num_rows($result);

if($length>0)
{
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo $rows['name'];
       echo "<img src='$rows[url]' />";
   }
}
else
{
   echo "Nothing to display";
}
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos;");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query1);

if(empty($result)) {
    echo "nothing";
} else {
    echo "good";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much sums up the answer for this question: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

They even provided a sample code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //<--- here they check if number of rows returned is greater than 0 (so there is data to display)
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results"; //<----- nothing found
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Just modify this and you'll be good to go.